The stabilizer of a point in the connected Lorentz group
$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$For $n\geq 2$, the $n$-dimensional  connected Lorentz group is defined as $$\SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}=\{f\in M_n (\mathbb{R}):f^T\eta f=\eta, \det (f)=1,f^0_0>0\}$$ where $$\eta=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0&  \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Assume that $p=(E,E,0,\dotsc,0)$. I would appreciate if someone could help me  about proving this fact: The stabilizer of $p$ under $\SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}$ is $$\SO(n-2)\ltimes \mathbb{R}^{n-2},$$ the Euclidean group. By the stabilizer of $p$ under $\SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}$, I mean,   $\SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}_p =\{ f\in \SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}:fp=p\}$.

What does the symbol $\ltimes$ mean?

@IosifPinelis: semidirect product. In this situation, it is a semidirect product of Lie groups.

In $p = (E, E, 0, \dotsc, 0)$, is $E$ meant to stand for some non-$0$ real number?

@LSpice Yes. $E$ is a positive real number.

One may prove by direct computation that in order to stabilize $p$, your matrix $f$ must be a block matrix of the form:
$$ f = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \vec{v}^T \\
0 & 1 & -\vec{v}^T \\
&& U
\end{bmatrix} $$
where $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ and $U \in \mathrm{SO} \left( n-2 \right)$. This is because we must map the first two coordinates to themselves, but we can do any linear map on the $n-2$ remaining ones and they would still map to zero; and multiplying those coordinates by any vector $ \vec{v}^T $ still won't do anything, since they are zero.
The group of all matrices of the above form is identified with the Euclidean group that you wrote down.
